# Valores no Terminal para um programa

Tags: java

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, executando os seguintes comandos no terminal, `java -jar logisim-filename.jar adder-test.circ -tty table` eu obtenho uma tabela no próprio terminal, delimitada por tabulações, da seguinte maneira:

```
00 00 000

01 00 001

10 00 010 etc…
```

No meu programa eu preciso desses valores, só que eu não sei como a partir do terminal (que comando executar) pegar eles e transferir para meu programa para que eu faça o necessário, se alguém puder me falar se tem como fazer.

Edição:

Meu programa ele pega um arquivo .txt e retira esses dados, como se fosse dados de uma tabela verdade, só que, a leitura do .txt ta sendo feita dessa forma:

```
public class tt2vcd {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


       //Leitura do arquivo gerado pelo logisim
       String fileName = args[0];           
       FileReader entrada = new FileReader(fileName);
       BufferedReader entradaFormatada = new BufferedReader(entrada);
    //Denominada uma String arquivo para manipular o nome do Arquivo do logisim
    String arquivo = fileName;

    //Trocado o tipo de arquivo, não sendo mais .txt, e sim .vcd
    arquivo = arquivo.replace("txt","vcd");

    //definida a leitura do arquivo caractere por caractere
            int c =  entradaFormatada.read();
 //realiza o processo de gravação...
}}
```

Então o que eu to querendo fazer é a partir do terminal, obter esse tratamento duplo, utilizando uma tag, para quando o cara gerar a tabela verdade no terminal, eu extraio as informações pelo terminal, e quando o cara quiser utilizar o .txt eu extraio do .txt.

Estou utilizando o Windows mas tenho acesso ao linux também.

Comment: Adiciona o codigo na pergunta.

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional que você usa? Digo isso porque, em Linux, por exemplo, você consegue salvar o output do terminal para um arquivo texto. Tendo isso, fica fácil do seu programa acessar esse arquivo e fazer o que precisa fazer.

Comment: Se for Linux você pode fazer isto: logisim-filename.jar adder-test.circ -tty table > sometext.txt 

Esse comando irá salvar um txt com a saída do terminal, a partir disto como StatelessDev falou você pode ler o arquivo txt.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado, eu adicionei o código na pergunta, mas acho que vou fazer o que o StatelessDev falou, o programa já ta realizando o tratamento .txt numa boa, então acho que é o caminho, to usando o Windows, mas tenho acesso ao Linux. Carlos Heuberger meu programa precisa fazer o tratamento tanto pela linha de comando quanto por arquivo, usando uma tag (por exemplo), para a diferenciação. Obrigado novamente pessoal

Answer (score 1):

Só com essas informações fica difícil ser 100% assertivo, mas vamos lá:

Para passar argumentos via linha de comando (terminal), você pode passá-los separados por espaço. Algo como:

```
java -jar sua-app.jar 00 00 000 01 00 001
```

Esses valores são recebidos como parâmetros no método `main` através do array de Strings (nesse caso, chamado de `args`).
Para ler essas informações basta iterar o array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(final String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Para que o Java encontre a sua *classe principal* você precisa dizer qual é essa classe através do [arquivo `MANIFEST.MF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-the-manifest-mf-file-in-java).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, eu adicionei o código que eu to usando na pergunta, ainda não testei o que você falou, vou testar aqui, obrigado de novo.